# Does Update Select SQL Query has built in Queuing inside?

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I'm creating a sql query `UPDATE SELECT` and I just want to know what will happen if my `update select` query simultaneously executes. Will it have queueing per query on same table?

**Example:**

```
SQL_TABLE
STOCKS(Column) Value : 15
```

Then I execute `2 update select` on my sql_table which is like this :

This 2 queries execute **simultaneously** in same time.

- **The 1st query** : `update sql_table set stocks = (stocks - 10);`
- **The 2nd query** : `update sql_table set stocks = (stocks - 5);`

This 2 queries execute **simultaneously** in same time.

Will it have queuing inside that will pick one of this query to go 1st before the other 1?

Or same queries will get 15 as the value of stocks column?

Comment: the execution of query is per line so your 1st query executes 1st before the 2nd query.

Comment: Line by line, from top to bottom.

Comment: Are you saying these queries are executed simultaneously from different client apps? Not sequentially in one app? It's a bit unclear precisely what scenario you are describing. If you are dealing with queries from different clients, then if those clients use transactions it should remove the risk of unexpected results

Answer (score 0):

This is the result of your query.

`Table 1`

`stocks
   15`

1. update sql_table set stocks = (stocks - 10);
   Result will be : 15(stocks) - 10 = 5
   Then
2. update sql_table set stocks = (stocks - 5);
   Result is : 5(stocks) - 5 = 0

1st line of query/code will be executed 1st.